# Can't convert anotation into import

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, spring-boot-starter

I've been tring to configure my pom file to start a springboot project with maven. I configured it like this but I can't convert an annotation into an import in my class. The spring starter on my pom file show in red too. I'm using intellij.

[image]

```
<groupId>io.github.murillojndem</groupId>
<artifactId>vendas</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image]
[image]

Edit: corrected the spelling and the image. Still, same error.

Comment: I don't think `@SprinBoot` even exists.

Comment: Yeah. If I had to guess it would probably be @SpringBoot

Comment: I know Spring is misspelled on the annotation but even spelled correctly it's giving the same response.

Comment: Where did you read that you're supposed to have a `@SprinBoot` annotation? Perhaps you should **(re)read the Spring Boot guide**, because it's called **`@SpringBootApplication`**. Any Spring Boot tutorial will tell you that.

Comment: Corrected the spelling

Comment: Yeah, I didnt finish the complete @SpringBootApplication annotation just to show that it doesn't even appear anything

Comment: How did you create `pom.xml`? Did you use a Maven archetype to generate the app skeleton from? Did you try using Spring Initializr? Or did you just create an empty `pom.xml` trying to tweak it manually?

Comment: Created a project on Intellij following a maven archetype, then added Spring Boot Starter Parent from maven repository, and changed some stuff like a teacher on Udemy told.

Comment: Depending on the settings, IntelliJ might not automatically reimport the POM after making changes. You may have to explicitly refresh (there should be a hovering refresh button in the right-top corner of the pom, or otherwise use the refresh button on the Maven tab).

Answer (score -1):

You can do some stuffs to try fix it.
1- Click on the lamp on the top of anotation and look if there some guide to fix it.

If the first point not worked, so you follow the next step
2- open your bash and digit "mvn clean install"